# Integrate select2 or any custom select plugin in grapesjs Style manager

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2, grapesjs

The problem is the default `select` element in the html is not good so what I want is to implement **select2 plugin** for the `select` in the **Style manager** of the grapesjs. As you can see in the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/gsd45fuy/)** I have tried it and it works but the thing is if we change the value in `select` it is not firing the event *[the style change is not applying]*.

*Please check the fiddle and let me know the proper way to do it.*

Answer (score 2):

It  is probable that `select2` removes events attached to select element therefore you can't see the changes. However, you can programmatically set grapejs to change the style or device. See the example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fd2z5qsa/.

Here is the relevant part:

````
$('.gjs-devices').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  editor.setDevice(e.params.data.id);
});


$('#gjs-clm-states').on('select2:select', function (e) {
 selectorManager.setState(e.params.data.id);
});```
````

Comment: Nice solution but what will be don with other `select`  as per your answer we will have to rite an event for all `select` elements and there are some `select` in which there is no `ID` so that will also be an issue right.

Comment: I guess that would be a problem if you want to change an entire library select element. For other elements you might want to check the `e.params.data` and see if there are other ways to set the value.

Comment: ok, don't take this wrong, I am a beginner in `grapesjs` for other style values what will be the editor function.? like styles.??

Comment: @weBBer that's OK. Overwriting a function in an entire framework is a big job. For example,  I had to go through `grapesjs` documentation to find which function sets the device and which function update the style. Also, I had to find `e.params.data.id`. In other words you have to have a thorough knowledge of the API to find the related functions, and that is time consuming. In your fiddle I saw only two select elements, so I am not sure what other functions you are looking for.

Comment: when you click on an element you can see some style dropdowns in the right panel I was talking about them, is there any function sets their values. I was checking if there is a function that affects all style attributes.

Comment: I included that in my answer. This is the one `selectorManager.setState`